# The Object-Serialization-Issue: Dealing with Inheritance while Mapping Objects

Tags: json, oop, design-patterns, deserialization

I am struggling with the following Problem which is pretty common and I am not sure if properly solved by existing frameworks. I would call the problem object-mapping problem or object-serialization problem.

I am writing a Java program where I have an abstract object which has many implementations. This objects are then part of other objects. Now, I want to serialize/deserialize this to JSON. In general, I could have a very complex inheritance structure. For deserialization, I need a concrete Implementation/Constructor. Do common (JSON)-Serialization Frameworks like Jackson have a way to support this in a hassle-free manner. This should work not only for the classes that are directly serialized but also for their fields.

I consider this as a problem similar to ORM (and even a subproblem of that), where OOP conflicts with other "patterns".
In ORM there are usually discriminator columns to deal with that problem and of course, I need a similar approach here or some "Detectors/Discriminators" that detect the right Implementations.
Currently I am solving the issue by first mapping the objects to "Semi-Serialized" Objects by using Orika (not a nice way of doing this) and do the rest of the serialization using Jackson. This is nicer a nice way of doing this nor a hassle-free one.

Does anyone know a framework, that is good in such things? If so, Is there a good reference to use the framework for that kind of problems?

Comment: Googling for "Jackson inheritance" leads to this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization

Comment: Use OOP to model program responsibilities, not data. No mapping required.